# Pandemic: drawing player cards if already have 7 in hand

Tags: pandemic

In the game Pandemic, after completing your 4 actions the next step is to draw 2 player cards. If already holding 7 in hand, does the rule force you to draw additional cards and subsequently discard (or play event cards) to get back  to 7? Or do you so the draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must draw, then discard.

> After doing 4 actions, draw the top 2 cards together from the Player Deck.

There's nothing about the draw being optional in the rules.

Comment: Side note: a really big reason it's important that you can't decline to draw is that you lose the game when you run out of cards in the player deck. Skipping draws would potentially let you win instead!

Comment: @Jefromi, I presumed the OP knew that since it's surely what prompted the question he asked.

Comment: I thought he might just not have wanted to "waste" cards by discarding them.

Comment: @Jefromi, The only reason it's a waste is because it ends the game faster. Otherwise, draw 2 then discard 2 is purely beneficial. In fact, it's so beneficial that in Magic, you have spells that do exactly that, even though you lose the game if you run out of cards like in Pandemic.

Comment: I didn't say *I* think that, just that it was a guess based on the OP's phrasing (e.g. being forced to play event cards you might want to save). It is easy to see discarding location cards as a waste of cards you might use to cure.

Comment: @Jefromi, Noone suggested that discarding alone was good.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was just looking for confirmation to resolve this with an objector. :-)